# Kendo pdf export cuts content on bottom

Tags: html, pdf, kendo-ui, export

I am exporting an html to pdf using Kendo UI and the problem I am facing is html content gets cut weirdly in the pdf. You can try it on the [link](http://dojo.telerik.com/UWORa/7)

Below is the page with shortened content which works fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    button{
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .k-pdf-export{
      font-size: 70%;
      font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
     <button onclick="export_pdf()"> Export PDF </button>
     <div class="pdf-page">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
  <script>
    function export_pdf(){
         kendo.drawing.drawDOM($('.pdf-page'), {
            paperSize : "A4",
            margin : {
               top : "2cm",
               left : "1cm",
               right : "1cm",
               bottom : "1cm"
            }
         }).then(function(group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "export.pdf");
         }); 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when the content is larger, it gets cut weirdly. Try it into the snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
  <style>
    button{
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .k-pdf-export{
      font-size: 70%;
      font-family: "DejaVu Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
     <button onclick="export_pdf()"> Export PDF </button>
     <div class="pdf-page">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
   </div>
  <script>
    function export_pdf(){
         kendo.drawing.drawDOM($('.pdf-page'), {
            paperSize : "A4",
            margin : {
               top : "2cm",
               left : "1cm",
               right : "1cm",
               bottom : "1cm"
            }
         }).then(function(group) {
            kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group, "export.pdf");
         }); 
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get my content displayed nice in an A4 format like it is specified in the js export function? What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by changing font styles on the fly, just for the exported content. For most predictable results, use the same styles for the content displayed by the browser, and the exported content. In addition, it is recommended to register the **pako deflate** library and fonts for embedding in the PDF document.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/drawing-dom#configuration-Custom

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output#configuration-Custom

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/drawing/pdf-output#configuration-Compression

Here is an updated version of your example that works better:

http://dojo.telerik.com/UWORa/11

Comment: while your example works fine, in my case the problem still exists. I have been able to reduce the amount of empty space on the bottom, by using the attribute `scale: ratio`, but I am still enable to resolve my issue. I feel like I am doing hacks, and not the right thing